# how to scroll to a specific div when a radio button is clicked/changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to scroll the page to "#Table_Details" using the scroll plug in. But i can't seem to get it working.

When i click/change the radio(.ModemsSelect) button the page scrolls to the location of the radio button i just clicked instead of scrolling down the page where my table("#table_Details") is located. I am not sure if i am doing this right or what is going on.

```
$(".ModemsSelect,.ServicesSelect").change(function (e) {
    var data = $("#" + this.value).serialize();
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "classes/sCart.php?action=add",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: "html",
        radioButton: $(this).attr('class')
    });
    request.success(function (data) {
        //$(".in_cart").html("");//clear last item selected
        console.log("extra item added to cart");
        refreshCart();
        if (this.radioButton == "ModemsSelect") {
            $.scrollTo($('#Table_Details'));

            $("#icon_check_modem").html("");
            $("#icon_check_modem").html("<img src=\"../img/check_icon.png\">");
            $('.Modem_buttonNext').button("enable");
        } else if (this.radioButton == "ServicesSelect") {
            $("#icon_check_Installtype").html("");
            $("#icon_check_Installtype").html("<img src=\"../img/check_icon.png\">");
            $(".install_buttonNext").button("enable");
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: You should wait to scroll until you're done modifying the page's html. You're starting the `scrollTo` call, and jQuery calculates the position it needs to scroll into view. Then, you change the page layout with calls to `html()`, but jQuery already started the scroll movement. So, it doesn't wind up in the right place. My suggestion is to move that `scrollTo` call to the end, and wrap it in a `setTimeout` with like 500ms delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

working fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/ePstY/**

You must replace this:

```
$.scrollTo($('#Table_Details'));
```

with this:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#Table_Details').position().top}, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try doing it this

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#Table_Details").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Instead of this:

```
$.scrollTo($('#Table_Details'));
```

I got the code from this article: [SMOOTHLY SCROLL TO AN ELEMENT WITHOUT A JQUERY PLUGIN](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2010/01/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin/)

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewliu/32tRk/)

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.